# Why is pyplot's histogram giving two different colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

edit: What I am trying to reproduce is this histogram:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTmF7.png).

So I'm plotting a pretty large dataset of two different sets of times. But I'm getting a histogram with blue and orange bars.

[image]

Everywhere else I looked to see if someone has asked/answered this question yields results for wanting to change the colors. However, every other time I've used hist, I just get blue bars as default.

Here is my code:

```
filename='24.txt'
data=np.genfromtxt(filename, usecols=(0,3), skip_header=4)
bins=15    
entries, edges, _ = plt.hist(data,bins,)
```

[This is a relevant sample of my text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PQur.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are importing 2 columns from your text file, i.e., column 0 and column 3. Now your `data` contains two columns. When you plot a histogram using `hist`, it will plot two histograms: one for each column.

That is the reason you see two sets of bars: orange and blue. The histogram is plotted for a single dataset to see its distribution. It seems that you want two separate plots, each having a histogram of a single column.

To see a histogram with single color, you need to do

```
entries, edges, _ = plt.hist(data[:,0],bins)
```

for the first column (column index 0) and

```
entries, edges, _ = plt.hist(data[:,1],bins)
```

for the fourth column (column index 3)

Answer (score 1):

You are reading 2 columns in the file, so `data` has a shape `(n, 2)` where `n` is the number of lines. When calling the `hist()` function, it makes 2 histograms, one for each column.

If you want an histogram of the first of your 2 selected columns, you can use `plt.hist(data[:,0],bins)`.

Comment: @MaxD What is the question? I only see a question in the title: "Why are there 2 colors?" The answer is: Because there are 2 histograms.